Why equating the two cylinders $x^2+y^2=a^2$ and $x^2+z^2=a^2$, doesn't give their intersection?
I think the intersection of the two cylinders $x^2+y^2=a^2$ and $x^2+z^2=a^2$can be found by equating their equations:
$$x^2+y^2=x^2+z^2\quad\Rightarrow \quad y^2=z^2\quad\Rightarrow\quad y=\pm z$$
But this way, I got equation of two planes $y=z$ and $y=-z$ which doesn't represent the region intersection of the two cylinders. I'm not sure what does these planes are supposed to represent. Here is the image:


Spoiler: By equating the equations you remove $a,.$

@KurtG. I don't see why it is the problem. If the second equation had $b^2$ on the other side, equating the equations would not lead to their intersection, as it gives $y^2-z^2=a^2-b^2$.

Equating those equations has nothing to do with finding the intersection of the two cylinders. That intersection is described by the system of the two equations. If you throw away what $a$ is how on earth is Desmos supposed to know about $a,?$

The intersection equation gives you $y^2 = z^2$. However $x,y$ are still constrained to lie on a cylinder so $x^2 + y^2 = a^2$. You need to retain one of the equations for the cylinders to have a complete description of the intersection.
